# javascript : my appendChild only works once

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid, appendchild, queryselector

I have a `<div id="incontent"></div>`  in which I am generating elements using javascript... here is my script :

```
        var lastId = 0; // initialise ID
    
        function MyFunction( var1, var2, var3) {
        const incontent = document.getElementById('incontent');
        incontent.innerHTML+= var1 + var2 + (var3 ? ' (var3=' + var3 + ')' : '');
            if (var3 === 'descforalink') {
            incontent.innerHTML += `<div class="contentLink"><p>a link</p></div></div>`;
            }
        }
        //manages the click on possible 
        document.getElementById('incontent').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        lastId++ ; // for a different ID
        });

        // element in which to instantiate the contentDATA for another rendering...
        const contentDATA = document.getElementById('contentDATA');

        // contentDATA content is received
        contentDATA.addEventListener(MyMouv.Descperso, ({ data }) => {
        var divques1 = '<div class="contentDesc col-12"><p>';
        var divques2 = '</p>';
        var divques3 = '</div>';
        var contentallbtns = '';
        var contentbtnsbefore = '<div class="col-12 contentLink">';
        var contentbtnsafter = '</div></div>';

        MyFunction('', divques1 + data.text + divques2 , data.var3, divques3);
        // if actions buttons/links
        if (data.actions) {
        var btns = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.actions.length; i++) { if (i> 0) {btns += ' ';}
            let act = data.actions[i];
            btns += '<a class="mybtn"' + ' data-val="' + act.value + '">' + act.title + '</a>';
            contentallbtns = contentbtnsbefore + btns + contentbtnsafter;
            }
            MyFunction('',contentallbtns);
            }

            //building tags
            var startB = document.createElement('section');
            var myiddesc = 'iddesc-'+lastId ;
            startB.setAttribute('id', myiddesc );
            startB.setAttribute('class', 'thesection');
            document.getElementById('incontent').appendChild(startB);
            var startB2 = document.createElement('div');
            startB2.setAttribute('class', 'container');
            startB.appendChild(startB2);
            var startB3 = document.createElement('div');
            startB3.setAttribute('class', 'row MyRow');
            startB2.appendChild(startB3);

            document.querySelector('div.MyRow').appendChild(document.querySelector('div.contentDesc'));
            document.querySelector('div.MyRow').appendChild(document.querySelector('div.contentLink'));
            });
```

This generates the first time a structure of this type:

```
<section id="iddesc-0" class="thesection">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row MyRow">
                <div class="contentDesc">
                    <p>Hello World</p>(var3=descforalink)
                </div>
                <div class="contentLink">
                    <p>a link</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

This is what I want ... but when another section is created, with actions, this structure appears:

```
<section id="iddesc-0" class="thesection">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row MyRow">
            <div class="contentDesc">
                <p>Hello World</p>(var3=descforalink)
            </div>
            <div class="contentLink">
                <p>a link</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<div class="contentDesc">
    <p>Hello World</p>(var3=descforalink)
</div>
<div class="contentLink">
    <a class="mybtn" data-val="banana">banana</a><a class="mybtn" data-val="orange">orange</a>
</div>
<section id="iddesc-1" class="thesection">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row MyRow">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

so the `appendchild()` on `document.querySelector('div.MyRow').appendChild(document.querySelector('div.contentDesc')); document.querySelector('div.MyRow').appendChild(document.querySelector('div.contentLink'));`only works once ... how can i change that? Always place my div div `class="contentDesc"` and `class="contentLink"` in the div `class="row MyRow"` ? Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 1):

If you use `appendChild` on an element that's already in the DOM, it **moves** the element from where it is to the new location. It doesn't make a copy of it.

If you want to make a copy and then append the copy, use [`cloneNode(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode):

```
document.querySelector('div.MyRow').appendChild(
    document.querySelector('div.contentDesc').cloneNode(true)
);
document.querySelector('div.MyRow').appendChild(
    document.querySelector('div.contentLink').cloneNode(true)
);
```

**but**, I'm not sure you really want to do that. You're creating a new section which you're referencing a `startB` but then you aren't appending `startB` to anything. Perhaps you meant to append it instead of one of the above.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response ... my startB generates a section in the <div id="incontent"> tag ... indeed I forgot to copy document.getElementById('incontent').appendChild(startB);I added it to my code ...

Comment: And I just want to place "contentDesc" and "contentLink" always in the same place: in the div class="row myRow" of its section

Comment: I don't quite understand the cloning system ... for me the tags were created every time contentDATA receives content ... so for me it was already in the DOM hence the use of appenchild( ) ... so my reasoning is wrong?

Comment: @Molly - It's a bit hard to follow the way it is in the question right now. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).